# adb dont recognize my cell phone when i turn on the tethering usb android 11

Tags: adb

When I turn on USB tethering on my Android 11 phone adb don't recognize my cell phone anymore:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
MAX3210725006638        device


adb devices
List of devices attached
```

Comment: If your PC is runing Windows open Windows device manager and check what is change when you enable USB tethering. May be one driver is not correctly installed. in such a case you can delete the device and next time it is recognized you have the chance to select the correct driver for installation.

Comment: when in file transfer mode the pc recognizes the phone as a portable device, when in tethering mode it recognizes it as android usb ethernet

Comment: USB has the possibility to provide more than one "device type" at a time. This is done by changing it's type to an "USB compound device" which can have multiple USB "sub-devices". For example if you enable Android Debug Bridge and file transfer mode at the same time you will see in device explorer the USB compound device and as children adb interface and USB MTP device (if you change device manager view to "by connection").